# Automatic hyphenation in doc

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I can't find any information in the documentation about `python-docx`. How do i enable auto hyphenation of words in `python-docx` lib? It's possible?

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @Hariharan Ragothaman recheck my post